# Delete Values in table PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html

Good evening, I have a question, I need to eliminate time values in the table below, if it is "Entrada" to display less value when and if the "Salida" of higher value. In conclusion should be generally one record per day, unless there are two entrances and exits.
[image: Description]

```
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_ASSOC) ) {
    $hor=substr(getDiferenciaHorasTrabajadas($line['entrada'],$line['salida']),0,2)+$hor;
    $min=substr(getDiferenciaHorasTrabajadas($line['entrada'],$line['salida']),3 ,2)+$min;
    $seg=substr(getDiferenciaHorasTrabajadas($line['entrada'],$line['salida']),6 ,2)+$seg;

    $horR=substr($line['horas'],0,2)+$horR;
    $minR=substr($line['horas'],3,2)+$minR;
    $segR=substr($line['horas'],6,2)+$segR;
    echo $line[''];

    if (condition) {
            # code...
    }

    echo "<tr><td>". $line['asi_fecha']."</td><td>". $line['entrada']."</td><td>". $line['salida']."</td><td>"
        .getDiferenciaHorasTrabajadas($line['entrada'],$line['salida']) ."</td><td>". $line['horas']."</td>"; 
    $entradaaux=$line['entrada'];
    $salidaaux=$line['entrada'];

    if (strtotime(getDiferenciaHoras(getDiferenciaHorasTrabajadas($line['entrada'],$line['salida']), $line['horas'])) >= strtotime("00:00:00")) {
        echo "<td style='color:blue;'>". getDiferenciaHoras(getDiferenciaHorasTrabajadas($line['entrada'],$line['salida']), $line['horas'])."</td></tr>";
    } else {
            echo "<td style='color:red;'>". getDiferenciaHoras(getDiferenciaHorasTrabajadas($line['entrada'],$line['salida']),$line['horas'])."</td></tr>";
    }
}
```

Query

```
select a.asi_fecha, a.asi_accion, a.asi_hora as salida,
    addtime(
        timediff(cast(ifnull(time(hor_salidaM),'00:00:00') as time),
        cast(ifnull(time(hor_entradaM),'00:00:00') as time)),
        timediff(
            cast(ifnull(time(hor_salidaT),'00:00:00') as time),
            cast(ifnull(time(hor_entradaT),'00:00:00')as time)
        )
    ) as horas,
    dia_descripcion, t2.asi_fecha, t2.asi_accion,t2.asi_hora as entrada
from (
    asistencia a, usuario u, dia d, horario h 
    join(
        select asi_fecha, asi_accion, asi_hora 
        from asistencia, usuario, dia 
        where asi_usu_id = usu_id and usu_cedula = '%s' and dia_id = dayofweek(asi_fecha)-1 and asi_accion = 'Entrada'  
    ) as t2
)
where a.asi_usu_id = u.usu_id and u.usu_cedula = '%s' and d.dia_id = dayofweek(a.asi_fecha)-1
    and a.asi_accion = 'Salida' and a.asi_fecha = t2.asi_fecha
    and h.hor_pos_id = (
        select pos_id 
        from postulacion 
        where pos_usu_id=(
            select usu_id from usuario where usu_cedula='%s'
        )
    )
    and hor_dia_id = dia_id and t2.asi_hora < a.asi_hora
group by a.asi_fecha,t2.asi_hora
```

Comment: You only want to modify the display, not the actual data, right? You should update your SQL query so you only get rows you want to display.

Comment: How? the Query is very complex!

Comment: I don't know, you didn't include the query but there should be a way to.

Comment: I add query in question.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly are you asking? You say that you want one record per day but e.g. for the date 2015-12-01 you highlighted both rows, does it mean that you want to hide both? Also you specify that the condition is that Salida must be > than Entrada but that seems irrelevant, because in the example "Salida" is always > than "Entrada".

Comment: You need to edit your question. it is unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: I need show only one row per day, if is "Salida" show the less value if is "Entarda" the higher value